# Is there a UI class on Android like UINavigationController on cocoa touch?

Tags: android

I hope to make an Android version of my iPhone app.

Cocoa touch has UINavigationaController which can control the navigation of views(controller). It is special for the mobile device which has the small size screen.

Is there a UI class on Android like UINavigationController?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Android and iPhone SDKs use different paradigms for how they control views, etc.  Its not really possible to take your iPhone app, rename some classes and turn it into an Android app.

I highly suggest you go read through the introductory Android documentation before going any further, so that you can understand the Android way of doing things.  Start out with [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html) and work from there.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, android does have an equivalent, which is part of the Fragment / FragmentManager system documented here [Fragment back stack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#BackStack)

Answer (score 0):

Not really.  The closest thing would be an Activity with Buttons and Intents that you create.  Read the document Mayra linked to.